# How to check the last character of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, char

I want to find the last character of a string in C# and then put it in an `if` statement.

Then if the last character is equal to 'A', 'B' or 'C' a certain action should be performed.

How do I get the last character of a string in C#?

Comment: Last character position... isn't that just `length-1`?

Comment: Read the documentation on `String` class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: If you are coming to C# from VB, you might find "C# & VB.NET Conversion" helpful. 

http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596003196/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00

Comment: Read the MSDN Documentary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397507(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There is absolutely nothing unclear about this question what-so-ever. It is entirely clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use the `EndsWith()` method of strings:

```
if (string.EndsWith("A") || string.EndsWith("B") || string.EndsWith("C"))
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Heres the MSDN article explaining this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 23):

I assume you don't actually want the last character *position* (`yourString.Length - 1`), but the last character *itself*. You can find that by indexing the string with the last character position:

```
yourString[yourString.Length - 1]
```

Comment: Or even simpler, use the index from end operator i.e. yourString[^1] — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes

Answer (score 14):

`string` is a `zero based` array of `char`.

```
char last_char = mystring[mystring.Length - 1];
```

Regarding the second part of the question, if the char is `A`, `B`, `C`

Using `if statement`

```
char last_char = mystring[mystring.Length - 1];
if (last_char == 'A' || last_char == 'B' || last_char == 'C')
{
    //perform action here
}
```

Using `switch statement`

```
switch (last_char)
{
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
    // perform action here
    break
}
```

Comment: That `if` would look better as `switch`, imo.

Comment: i wrote as switch only but, in question `if` statement is needed!

Answer (score 11):

There is an **index-from-end operator** that looks like this: `^n`.

```
var list = new List<int>();

list[^1]  // this is the last element
list[^2]  // the second-to-last element
list[^n]  // etc.
```

The [official documentation about indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) describes this operator. Checking the last character therefore looks like:

```
string str = "foo";
bool ends_with_o = str.Length != 0 && str[^1] == 'o';
```

Without a length check, this code fails at runtime if `str == ""`:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was 
outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)
   ...
```

Answer (score 4):

With recent C# versions, one can just use `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()` on a string in C# to return last char.

```
string sample = "sample string";
char lastCharacter = sample.Last(); 
if (lastCharacter == 'A' || lastCharacter == 'B' || lastCharacter == 'C') 
{
     Console.WriteLine(lastCharacter);
}
else if (lastCharacter == 'g')
{
     Console.WriteLine($"found! {char.ToUpper(lastCharacter)}");
}
else if (sample.EndsWith("ing"))
{
     Console.WriteLine($"use for multiple characters! {sample}");
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values for default char

Answer (score 2):

Since **C# 8.0**, you can use new syntactic forms for `System.Index` and `System.Range` hence addressing specific characters in a `string` becomes trivial. Example for your scenario:

```
var lastChar = aString[^1..]; // aString[Range.StartAt(new Index(1, fromEnd: true))

if (lastChar == "A" || lastChar == "B" || lastChar == "C")
    // perform action here
```

Full explanation here: [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: So in this new-fangled C# version, `^n` means the index `n` from the end.  But ... how about making it just `aString[^1]`, thereby a `char` rather than a `string`?

Comment: The question was to find the last character and compare it with "A" and "B" (which are strings), not 'A' and 'B' (which would be characters).

Comment: The only actual question in the question text is: "How do I get the last character?"  Furthermore, these "strings" are not marked up as code, so it's a reasonable supposition that they are using English prose quotation marks rather than code quotation marks.  If you interpret them as code, you have a problem in that a character can't be equal to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the last character by using LINQ, with `myString.Last()`, although this is likely slower than the other answers, and it gives you a `char`, not a `string`.

Comment: If you do : 
myString.Last().ToString() 
you will get the last char converted into a string again. It is perhaps very readable for some coders, others likes a more array index approach casting directly : 
string last = field[field.Length - 1].ToString();
Direct cast to string of char is not allowed.

Comment: @ToreAurstad if length of the string is 0 you will get out of bounds exception