# How to determine if string ends in vowel or consonant?

Tags: c#, string

hello my teacher gave me a task to create a program to :
(1) find how many vowels are there in a string
(2) and determine if a string ends in a vowel or consonant

I did the first requirement but I had no idea about the second one. since I'm still a beginner in this field. can anyone help me? what should I do with the second requirement?

and the result should be like this :

Enter a string: stack; Ends in consonant; Total Vowels: 1

Comment: could you show your code of the 1st requirement - just edit your question

Comment: Many questions: Case sensitive A != a? Accent à!=a? Diacritic? Grapheme and ligature, is `œ` a vowel? Balck or White, so no puntuaction or space? If you list the possible vowel. And the last **letter** is not in the list, is it a consonant? there are letter that an not vowel nor consonant. What if both, letter than are from the ligature of a know vowel and consonant?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you know how to [get string end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14794267/1997232)? What [are vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17764680/1997232)? What can't you do exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a character is a vowel or consonant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764680/check-if-a-character-is-a-vowel-or-consonant)

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow Blue Azzure,

there are many ways to get this second task done. One approach could be

1. Get the last character as char (`char ch = lc[lc.Length - 1];`)
2. Make the text lowercase (`var lc = ch.ToLowerInvariant()`)
3. Evaluating the character type:

   - checking agains the vowels (e.g. `ch == 'a'`): if true -> it is a vowel
   - checking the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)-value of the character is inside the lowercase letters range (`c >= 97 && c <= 122`): if true -> it is a consonant
   - otherwise the last character is neither vowel nor consonant

Comment: Sorry, my fault: It should be ```ToLowerInvariant()```.

Comment: what does "var" mean? because I still have an error on that

Comment: Var is C# feature that helps you (or confuses you - there are multiple opinions in the community about that) to not write the explicit variable type if it is defined implicitly by an assignment or alike. In the example here the ```string.ToLowerInvariant()``` function returns a ```string``` so the compiler knows implicitly that lc must be a string as well. If you like to replace the ```var``` by ```string``` it's correct syntax as well.

Comment: `text.ToLowerInvariant()` on the whole text is a bad idea. Why whould you duplicate the entire book if you just need the last char? The method is also available on char https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tolowerinvariant?view=net-5.0

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. It would be better to switch 1 and 2. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Linq approach

```
char[] vocals = "aeiouAEIOU".ToCharArray();
string input = "testo";

int vocalCount = input.Count(vocals.Contains);
bool endsWithVocal = vocals.Any(input.Last().Equals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into char array then use array[length-1] to access last character and check it through for loop if it contains 'a,e,i,o,u'.
If it does it is vowel otherwise not :)